# After completing Drag-and-Drop game, need image to pop up with a button for next game

Tags: popup

The drag-and drop game works nicely. But after completing the game, I have a text box that I would to replace with a pop-up image and a button on that....

```js
var winMessage = root.winMessage;
```

I tried variations like root.winImage but that doesn't work.

And then...

```js
root.onWin = function() {

  winMessage.text = "WINNER!";
  winMessage.alpha = 0;
  winMessage.y = winMessage.originalY + 60;
  createjs.Tween.get(winMessage).to({
    alpha: 1,
    y: winMessage.originalY
  }, 500, createjs.Ease.backInOut);
};
```

How do I make it work - newbie here - Thanks for any help!!